# Angular Dropdown Change() vs valueChanges.subscribe

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

I have an Angular form built using Reactive Forms. The form contains 3 select elements. I want to add the value change detection to one dropdown and other two will change accordingly to the values of the first dropdown. Between **Change()** and **valueChanges.subscribe**, which will be the best to use and what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

They are fundamentally the same thing, each time the value of your dropdown changes, a function that change the value of the two other dropdowns is executed.
`valueChanges` is an Observable, you have to unsubscribe from it at some point, for instance when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your use case

1. if your list contain an autocomplete or a realtime search to fill options i recommand the use valueChanges that returns an observable.
2. if it's a simple dropdown list use change event instead it's simple and no need to use valueChange and handle unsubscribes

Comment: The first select box contain location and others have the staffs' name from the location. in this case, is it better to use simple (change) event?